# To get spacing between Bootstrap 5 rows do I need to use gutter and row margin?

Tags: bootstrap-5

Using Bootstrap 5 it seems that use of gutter classes does not put any vertical space between row elements, it only puts space if a single row element has more than 12 columns and wraps round on display.

I tend to use a row when the content is going to be a single row on the main platform I am developing for (iPad), so I'm using `mb-2` to put a margin between each row. But sometimes the content is too large for smaller devices such as phones and so it wraps and then I get no space between first half of the row and the second half of the row that is now rendered between it, so I have added `gy-2` as well

So am I right in thinking that in most cases you need to add and **mb** (margin bottom) class and a `gy` (gutter vertical) class to most rows, or have I misunderstood this?

```
<div class="row gy-2 mb-2">
    <div class="col">
        <span class="ps-2">
            <label>
                All tracks composed by 
            </label>
            <span>
                <a href="/composer.start?cid=0$=Composer$2682&amp;title=Composers+%2F+Johann+Sebastian+Bach" class="small figure-caption">
                    Johann Sebastian Bach
                </a>
                <label class="small figure-caption">
                     
                </label>
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row gy-2 mb-2">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-auto">
        <span>
            <button id="show_movements_button" type="btn" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#movements_id">
                Show Movements
            </button>
        </span>
        <span>
            <button id="show_credits_button" type="btn" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#credits_id">
                Show All Credits
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-auto ms-sm-auto">
        <span>
            <span class="input-group">
                <span for="filter" id="filterlabel" class="input-group-text">
                    Filter
                </span>
                <input type="text" id="filter" name="filter" onkeyup="filterOnly()" class="form-control">
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got it right, you need to use `mb` to add vertical space between each row and `gy` to add vertical space between the columns of each row (when the row wraps).

You can also add `mb` to the columns to achieve the same result:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wb4s1ofc/)

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like that. Some top-of-the-head options...

- Use bottom margin, as `mb-2`
- Use Y-axis margin, as `my-2`
- Use a custom class on a container element, as `row-gutter-2 {margin-bottom: $spacer * .5;}`